# Which one method implemented by Android's Activity Class is NOT A Template Method?

Tags: java, android

A Template Method is a method that you may implement, but you must never call so which one method implemented by Android's Activity Class is NOT A Template Method?

Comment: If you take a look at official doc, you can see that there are a lot of methods like that.

Comment: So, did I answer your question?

Comment: I am glad it helped, you can accept my answer so other people will see that the question was answered :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I probably did not understand the question correctly, however I guess you are talking about lifecycle's methods:

- onCreate()
- onStart()
- onRestart()
- onResume()
- onPause()
- onStop()
- onDestroy()

Since they all can be implemented but should never be directly called by application's code. Every other method of `Activity` is not "template" (e.g. `findViewById` or `getContext`).

[Official documentation for Activity class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity)